# How to Add Node Loader in Serverless ESBuild to Resolve ".node" Files Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, serverless-framework, esbuild

I'm currently working on a serverless project where I'm using ESBuild to bundle my JavaScript code for AWS Lambda functions. Everything has been working smoothly so far, but I've run into a situation where I need to load a Node.js module that is not natively supported by ESBuild.

Whenever I run the serverless package command, I encounter the following error:

```
✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/.pnpm/nodejs-polars-darwin-arm64@0.8.2/node_modules/nodejs-polars-darwin-arm64/nodejs-polars.darwin-arm64.node
```

Specifically, I need to use a Node.js module loader to load a module that contains native bindings with a .node extension. However, ESBuild doesn't seem to support this out of the box, and I'm not sure how to configure it to work with a custom Node.js module loader.

I've read about similar issues with Webpack, where you can use the node-loader package to load Node.js modules, but I'm not sure how to achieve the same result with ESBuild in a serverless environment.

Has anyone successfully configured ESBuild to work with a custom Node.js module loader to resolve .node files in a serverless context? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Dhruvgarg no, I'm still waiting for their official release to handle it. I have, however went back to WebPack

Comment: I resolved the issue, by using a lambda layer

Comment: @Dhruvgarg nice. Can you post an answer here and I'll try it.

Comment: I have added it. I have tried to add a detailed answer, let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using lambda layers. I was trying to package a platform-specific library (mongodb-zstd).

you can follow these steps:

- create a new node project
- add the package that you want to upload as lambda layer in package.json

```js
{
    "name": "nodejs",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "@mongodb-js/zstd": "^1.2.0",
        "@mongodb-js/zstd-linux-arm64-gnu": "1.2.0"
    }
}
```

- zip the project including node_modules
- upload zip as a lambda layer from AWS console: Lambda -> Additional Resources -> layers -> create layer

Now in your serverless file, you can reference the lambda layer:

```
functions: {
        hello: {
            handler: 'handlers.hello',
            timeout: 30,
            layers: [`arn:aws:lambda:region:\${self:custom.accountId.\${self:custom.stage}}:layer:mongo-zstd`],
        }
    }
```

references:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/chapter-layers.html
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/layers