No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../rust.linux-x64-gnu.node
I am trying to use rust in aws lambda so I am using napi for building pre-compiled Node.js addons in Rust or for using rust from nodejs
but when I am trying to get the functions that i converted from rust to js, I am getting this error when i am trying to deploy into aws lambda
Bundling asset MyAppStack/lambda/Code/Stage...
✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../rust.linux-x64-gnu.node

    ../index.js:188:38:
      188 │               nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-x64-gnu.node')
          ╵                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 error

That's how I am trying to use the code
import { Hono } from 'hono'
import { handle } from 'hono/aws-lambda'
import {scrapeTextFromUrls} from "@gen-fellow/rust-lib"
const app = new Hono()

app.get('/', async (c) => {
    const urls = ["https://www.google.com"]
    const text = scrapeTextFromUrls(urls) //this is the function that is being converted from Rust to JS
    return c.json(text)
})

export const handler = handle(app)

in this file i am getting the error
No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../rust.linux-x64-gnu.node
see the highlighted part of code
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */
/* prettier-ignore */

/* auto-generated by NAPI-RS */

const { existsSync, readFileSync } = require('fs')
const { join } = require('path')

const { platform, arch } = process

let nativeBinding = null
let localFileExisted = false
let loadError = null

function isMusl() {
  // For Node 10
  if (!process.report || typeof process.report.getReport !== 'function') {
    try {
      const lddPath = require('child_process').execSync('which ldd').toString().trim()
      return readFileSync(lddPath, 'utf8').includes('musl')
    } catch (e) {
      return true
    }
  } else {
    const { glibcVersionRuntime } = process.report.getReport().header
    return !glibcVersionRuntime
  }
}

switch (platform) {
  case 'android':
    switch (arch) {
      case 'arm64':
        localFileExisted = existsSync(join(__dirname, 'rust.android-arm64.node'))
        try {
          if (localFileExisted) {
            nativeBinding = require('./rust.android-arm64.node')
          } else {
            nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-android-arm64')
          }
        } catch (e) {
          loadError = e
        }
        break
      case 'arm':
        localFileExisted = existsSync(join(__dirname, 'rust.android-arm-eabi.node'))
        try {
          if (localFileExisted) {
            nativeBinding = require('./rust.android-arm-eabi.node')
          } else {
            nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-android-arm-eabi')
          }
        } catch (e) {
          loadError = e
        }
        break
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported architecture on Android ${arch}`)
    }
    break
  case 'win32':
    switch (arch) {
      case 'x64':
        localFileExisted = existsSync(
          join(__dirname, 'rust.win32-x64-msvc.node')
        )
        try {
          if (localFileExisted) {
            nativeBinding = require('./rust.win32-x64-msvc.node')
          } else {
            nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-win32-x64-msvc')
          }
        } catch (e) {
          loadError = e
        }
        break
      case 'ia32':
        localFileExisted = existsSync(
          join(__dirname, 'rust.win32-ia32-msvc.node')
        )
        try {
          if (localFileExisted) {
            nativeBinding = require('./rust.win32-ia32-msvc.node')
          } else {
            nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-win32-ia32-msvc')
          }
        } catch (e) {
          loadError = e
        }
        break
      case 'arm64':
        localFileExisted = existsSync(
          join(__dirname, 'rust.win32-arm64-msvc.node')
        )
        try {
          if (localFileExisted) {
            nativeBinding = require('./rust.win32-arm64-msvc.node')
          } else {
            nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-win32-arm64-msvc')
          }
        } catch (e) {
          loadError = e
        }
        break
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported architecture on Windows: ${arch}`)
    }
    break
  case 'darwin':
    localFileExisted = existsSync(join(__dirname, 'rust.darwin-universal.node'))
    try {
      if (localFileExisted) {
        nativeBinding = require('./rust.darwin-universal.node')
      } else {
        nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-darwin-universal')
      }
      break
    } catch {}
    switch (arch) {
      case 'x64':
        localFileExisted = existsSync(join(__dirname, 'rust.darwin-x64.node'))
        try {
          if (localFileExisted) {
            nativeBinding = require('./rust.darwin-x64.node')
          } else {
            nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-darwin-x64')
          }
        } catch (e) {
          loadError = e
        }
        break
      case 'arm64':
        localFileExisted = existsSync(
          join(__dirname, 'rust.darwin-arm64.node')
        )
        try {
          if (localFileExisted) {
            nativeBinding = require('./rust.darwin-arm64.node')
          } else {
            nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-darwin-arm64')
          }
        } catch (e) {
          loadError = e
        }
        break
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported architecture on macOS: ${arch}`)
    }
    break
  case 'freebsd':
    if (arch !== 'x64') {
      throw new Error(`Unsupported architecture on FreeBSD: ${arch}`)
    }
    localFileExisted = existsSync(join(__dirname, 'rust.freebsd-x64.node'))
    try {
      if (localFileExisted) {
        nativeBinding = require('./rust.freebsd-x64.node')
      } else {
        nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-freebsd-x64')
      }
    } catch (e) {
      loadError = e
    }
    break
  case 'linux':
    switch (arch) {
      case 'x64':
        if (isMusl()) {
          localFileExisted = existsSync(
            join(__dirname, 'rust.linux-x64-musl.node')
          )
          try {
            if (localFileExisted) {
              nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-x64-musl.node')
            } else {
              nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-linux-x64-musl')
            }
          } catch (e) {
            loadError = e
          }
        } else {
          localFileExisted = existsSync(
            join(__dirname, 'rust.linux-x64-gnu.node')
          )
          try {
            if (localFileExisted) {
             // ------------------here is the problem --------------------------------
              nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-x64-gnu.node')
            } else {
              nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-linux-x64-gnu')
            }
          } catch (e) {
            loadError = e
          }
        }
        break
      case 'arm64':
        if (isMusl()) {
          localFileExisted = existsSync(
            join(__dirname, 'rust.linux-arm64-musl.node')
          )
          try {
            if (localFileExisted) {
              nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-arm64-musl.node')
            } else {
              nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-linux-arm64-musl')
            }
          } catch (e) {
            loadError = e
          }
        } else {
          localFileExisted = existsSync(
            join(__dirname, 'rust.linux-arm64-gnu.node')
          )
          try {
            if (localFileExisted) {
              nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-arm64-gnu.node')
            } else {
              nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-linux-arm64-gnu')
            }
          } catch (e) {
            loadError = e
          }
        }
        break
      case 'arm':
        if (isMusl()) {
          localFileExisted = existsSync(
            join(__dirname, 'rust.linux-arm-musleabihf.node')
          )
          try {
            if (localFileExisted) {
              nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-arm-musleabihf.node')
            } else {
              nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-linux-arm-musleabihf')
            }
          } catch (e) {
            loadError = e
          }
        } else {
          localFileExisted = existsSync(
            join(__dirname, 'rust.linux-arm-gnueabihf.node')
          )
          try {
            if (localFileExisted) {
              nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-arm-gnueabihf.node')
            } else {
              nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-linux-arm-gnueabihf')
            }
          } catch (e) {
            loadError = e
          }
        }
        break
      case 'riscv64':
        if (isMusl()) {
          localFileExisted = existsSync(
            join(__dirname, 'rust.linux-riscv64-musl.node')
          )
          try {
            if (localFileExisted) {
              nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-riscv64-musl.node')
            } else {
              nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-linux-riscv64-musl')
            }
          } catch (e) {
            loadError = e
          }
        } else {
          localFileExisted = existsSync(
            join(__dirname, 'rust.linux-riscv64-gnu.node')
          )
          try {
            if (localFileExisted) {
              nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-riscv64-gnu.node')
            } else {
              nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-linux-riscv64-gnu')
            }
          } catch (e) {
            loadError = e
          }
        }
        break
      case 's390x':
        localFileExisted = existsSync(
          join(__dirname, 'rust.linux-s390x-gnu.node')
        )
        try {
          if (localFileExisted) {
            nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-s390x-gnu.node')
          } else {
            nativeBinding = require('@gen-fellow/rust-lib-linux-s390x-gnu')
          }
        } catch (e) {
          loadError = e
        }
        break
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported architecture on Linux: ${arch}`)
    }
    break
  default:
    throw new Error(`Unsupported OS: ${platform}, architecture: ${arch}`)
}

if (!nativeBinding) {
  if (loadError) {
    throw loadError
  }
  throw new Error(`Failed to load native binding`)
}

const { scrapeWebsite, scrapeTextFromUrls, ModelTypes, generateEmbeddings } = nativeBinding

module.exports.scrapeWebsite = scrapeWebsite
module.exports.scrapeTextFromUrls = scrapeTextFromUrls
module.exports.ModelTypes = ModelTypes
module.exports.generateEmbeddings = generateEmbeddings


I would like to know how I should proceed further from here...
Please let me know if something is missing i will send it
Thank You

Getting error in this line
nativeBinding = require('./rust.linux-x64-gnu.node')

The question doesn't mention how "Bundling" is performed. Please, update it and add bundler config. The problem is specific to it

Hi @EstusFlask there is no config as I mention I am using napi-rs
but there is a build.rs file
`extern crate napi_build;
fn main() {
napi_build::setup();
}`

we can add a config napi_config

I see, so there's no other build tool used on deployment except napi-rs itself? This wasn't clear from the question. If you have custom config, consider adding it as it may be relevant. Since this could be a bug, I'd suggest to post an issue in napi-rs repo, especially since it isn't popular on SO

Yes, there's no other build tool. But we can't post an issue because it's working with node properly and this issue occurs only in aws lambda functions The same error occurs when I am trying the same thing using Cloudflare serverless functions

It's unclear at which moment the error occurs. Can you provide more context for it? The error looks like the one that comes from esbuild, and napirs seems to use esbuild only to build itself, not addons.  I didn't check thoroughly the details of the implementation of fn in both services. But I guess this means they build the app with esbuild, and the problem is how to use configure them to use native modules in general, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257724

Sure, I have a main file lambda/index.js(the code mentioned above) in which I am trying to import my package. When I run cdk deploy to deploy the function into AWS, I get this error. And I guess when we run the cdk deploy command without this package it makes a cdk.out in which the bundled code may be the deploy command using esbuild under the hood, so we are getting this error.

you can see the whole code here code
in my-app you can see the lambda function code

I got the answer, we can add externalModules like this in my-app-stack.ts
bundling: {
  externalModules: ["@gen-fellow/rust-lib"],
}

//my-app-stack.ts
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib'
import { Construct } from 'constructs'
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda'
import * as apigw from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway'
import { NodejsFunction } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs'

export class MyAppStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props)

    const fn = new NodejsFunction(this, 'lambda', {
      entry: 'lambda/index.ts',
      handler: 'handler',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
      bundling: {
        externalModules: ["@gen-fellow/rust-lib"],
      }
    })
    fn.addFunctionUrl({
      authType: lambda.FunctionUrlAuthType.NONE,
    })
    new apigw.LambdaRestApi(this, 'myapi', {
      handler: fn,
    })
  }
}

